# How to reference a library from execution assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have an application referencing let's say : DLL 1 and DLL 2.

Within the application the end user can write some code for some customized functions.

Inside my application I compile his code using :

```
// User's code
string code = @" ** User's code ** ";

// Create the provider
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

// Create the parameters
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

// Compile the user's code 
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
```

Before the compilation, I would like to add some references that are already used withing my application which are DLL 1 and DLL 2 (in order to let the user use some of my functions).

I tried to use GetExecutingAssembly, but it returns the main application assembly and I can't find how to get DLL 1 and DLL 2.

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
```

I don't know the path of the DLL's so the following instruction wont work :

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("C:\DLL1.dll");
```

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Comment: `GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()` then filter it ... also you know that it would be "different instance" of this assemblies loaded? so if your function (fx in dll 2) is modifing something in you program it will obviously not work

Comment: You could use something like this to get an assembly from its name `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SingleOrDefault(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the assembly location from a type defined within that assembly. So in your CompilerParameters you can reference them like this:

```
new CompilerParameters
{
    ReferencedAssemblies =
    {
        typeof(MyDll1.Type1).Assembly.Location,
        typeof(MyDll2.Type2).Assembly.Location
        //, etc
    }
    //, etc
}
```